# Numpy np.array() constructor behaving "inconsistently"

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have two Pandas dataframes, say `df1` and `df2` (shape (10, 15)), and I want to turn them into Numpy arrays, and then construct a Numpy array containing both of them (shape (2, 10, 15)). I'm currently doing this as follows:

```
data1 = df1.to_numpy()
data2 = df2.to_numpy()
data = np.array([data1, data2])
```

Now I'm trying to do this for many pairs of dataframes, and the code I'm using will break when I call `data.any()` for some of the pairs, giving the truth value error saying to use `any()` or `all()` (which I'm already doing). I started printing `data` when I saw this happening, and I noticed that the `np.array()` constructor will produce something that looks like `[[[...]]]` or `[array([[...]])]`.

The first one works fine, but the second doesn't. The difference isn't random with respect to the dataframes, it breaks for certain ones, but all of these dataframes are preprocessed & processed the same way and I've manually checked that the ones that don't work don't have any anomalies.

Since I can't provide much explicit code/data (code is pretty bulky, and arrays are 300 entries each), my main question is why the array constructor either gives `[[[...]]]` or `[array([[...]])]` forms, and why the second one doesn't like when I call `data.any()`?

Comment: can you post values returned by ```type(data1)```, ```type(data2```, ```type(data)```?

Comment: Look at `data.shape` and `data.dtype`.  In one case shape will be multidimensional and dtype numeric.  The other I expect is 1d with object dtype.  That's because the component arrays differ in shape.  `np.stack((data1, data2))` is another way of constructing the same numeric dtype (when shapes match).  It will raise an error when they don't match.

Comment: @hpaulj I looked at the shapes of each dataframe and found that when the construction "failed" one of the dataframes was of shape (9, 15) instead of (10, 15) - this occurred after processing. I fixed that issue and now all works well, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that after processing the data, some of the dataframes were missing rows (ie. of shape (x, 15) where x<10). The construction of the data array would give a shape of (2,) when this happened, so as long as both df1 and df2 had the same number of rows it worked fine.